# using AdMob in MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, admob, maui, .net-7.0

I have created an Android app in MAUI and intend to use AdMob in this project. However, I couldn't find a solution for it. I tried using a plugin called Plugin.MauiMTAdmob from the following link:
https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob
But this plugin only supports .NET 6, and I need it to work with .NET 7. If anyone has a solution, please share it here. Thank you.

I have developed an Android application using the MAUI framework and now I'm looking to integrate AdMob into this project. However, I haven't been able to find a suitable solution for my .NET 07 environment. I attempted to use a plugin called Plugin.MauiMTAdmob from the GitHub repository (https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob), but unfortunately, it only supports .NET 6, and I require compatibility with .NET 7. If anyone has encountered a similar situation and found a solution, I would greatly appreciate your guidance. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the supported frameworks of [Plugin.MauiMTAdmob 1.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.MauiMTAdmob/#supportedframeworks-body-tab), we could find that the compatible target framework(s) include `net7.0`.

So,please install the latest version of nuget : [Plugin.MauiMTAdmob 1.0.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.MauiMTAdmob/#versions-body-tab).

[image]

For how to use it, you can check link [MauiMTAdmob](https://github.com/marcojak/MauiMTAdmob).
And there is also a sample included in above link.